# Using this to change value within a nested function ($.get)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to change the value of `button.kill`. However I don't know how to access button.kill from within the get callback.

```
$("button.kill").click(function(){
    $.get("file.php",{ nbRandom: Math.random() },
    function(data){
        //set button.kill text to data
    });
});
```

There will be more than one button named kill and I want to ensure that I only update the one that the user has clicked.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
$("button.kill").click(function(){
    //save the variable that refers to the current object  to another variable
    var that = this;
    $.get("file.php",{ nbRandom: Math.random() },
    function(data){
        //set button.kill text to data
        //here this would not be the clicked element so we use that
         $(that).text(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
$("button.kill").click(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    $.get("file.php",{ nbRandom: Math.random() },
    function(data){
        t.text(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("button.kill").click(function(){
    var that = $(this);

    $.get("file.php",{ nbRandom: Math.random() },
    function(data){
        var text = that.val();
        //set button.kill text to data
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button.kill").click(function(){
    var item=$(this);
    $.get("file.php",{ nbRandom: Math.random() },
    function(data){
        item.text(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope. `this` has a different value within the callback.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Yea. My bad. i fixed that